# EC2 SSH connection broken pipe; cannot reconnect

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh

I successfully connected to an EC2 instance like so:

```
ssh -i .ssh/ec2docker.cer user@SOMEIP
```

After about an hour of using the instance, I leave and come back further two hours to this:

```
$ packet_write_wait: Connection to xx port 22: Broken pipe
```

Now, when trying to connect, nothing happens at all:

```
OpenSSH_7.9p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1b FIPS  26 Feb 2019
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug3: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 52: Including file /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/05-redhat.conf depth 0
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/05-redhat.conf
debug2: checking match for 'final all' host xxx originally xxx
debug3: /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/05-redhat.conf line 3: not matched 'final'
debug2: match not found
debug3: /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/05-redhat.conf line 5: Including file /etc/crypto-policies/back-ends/openssh.config depth 1 (parse only)
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/crypto-policies/back-ends/openssh.config
debug3: gss kex names ok: [gss-gex-sha1-,gss-group14-sha1-,gss-group1-sha1-]
debug3: kex names ok: [curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1]
debug1: configuration requests final Match pass
debug1: re-parsing configuration
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug3: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 52: Including file /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/05-redhat.conf depth 0
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/05-redhat.conf
debug2: checking match for 'final all' host xxx originally xxx
debug3: /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/05-redhat.conf line 3: matched 'final'
debug2: match found
debug3: /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/05-redhat.conf line 5: Including file /etc/crypto-policies/back-ends/openssh.config depth 1
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/crypto-policies/back-ends/openssh.config
debug3: gss kex names ok: [gss-gex-sha1-,gss-group14-sha1-,gss-group1-sha1-]
debug3: kex names ok: [curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1]
debug2: resolving "xxxx" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct
debug1: Connecting to xxx [xx] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file .ssh/ec2docker.cer type -1
debug1: identity file .ssh/ec2docker.cer-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.9
```

ssh does not terminate or give an error. The EC2 monitor shows that the instance is running with non-zero CPU utilization (around 25%) and non-zero network read and write.

Comment: I think your instance is small or micro, stop it and then start it, this should work.

Comment: @Adiii Yes, restarting the instance and I'm able to reconnect. But this problem happens again. I cannot keep restarting the instance.

Comment: this only happens your EC2 halt or there is more CPU intensive process, this is based on my experience, you can generate a ticket on AWS site.

Comment: also, check ssh audit log why this is happening

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for this issue was a memory leak in the application I was launching; it choked the whole EC2 instance.

Answer (score 0):

Have you check the public ip of your EC2 in AWS?

It seems like a reboot and if you do not have and "Elastic IP", now you have a new public ip.

Comment: The instance has not rebooted and the IP remains the same. By the way this issue is recurring - after rebooting the instance, I'm able to connect, but this happened again.

Answer (score 0):

Broken Pipe means Connection was lost

1) Click on EC2- Instance
2) Click on connect
3) Use the command to connect and it should work